# What is this effect called and where can I find a tutorial about it and reproduce it today?

Tags: davinci-resolve

So, I am a complete beginner in davinci resolve and the video editing world, I wonder how to create this amazing looking image effect:

It is the effect in the background btw.

Does anybody know what it is called and how to make it with davinci resolve 17?

Comment: Welcome! The sample you posted is not available in the US. Can you share another sample or describe the effect?

Comment: Try this one: https://youtube.com/shorts/Bk4PyW8-DqA?feature=share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video you link to is unavailable in the UK, but viewable using the Tor browser.

It's a series of motion blurred zoom-outs animated together, probably made using Adobe After Effects (eg [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnKXMxVcyHo)).

This page explains how to do motion blur transitions using Resolve and Fusion combined (Fusion comes as part of Resolve and is DaVinci's animation package, a bit like After Effects).

https://beginnersapproach.com/davinci-resolve-add-motion-blur/